# Issue pulling package from Gitlab Package Registry Maven

Tags: java, maven, gradle, package, gitlab

I try to pull packages from Gitlab Package Registry, but get error:
Could not find group:package:0.0.18-SNAPSHOT.
This package is really exist in package registry
Can anybody help?
am i missing something?

**I've tried with gradle:**
build.gradle:

```
repositories {
   mavenCentral(),
   maven {
       url "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/<group-id>/-/packages/maven"
       name "GitLab"
       credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
           name = "<deploy-token-username>"
           value = "deploy-token-value"
       }
       authentication {
           header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
       }
   }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("<group>:<package>:0.0.18-SNAPSHOT") 
}
```

**And with maven:**
pom.xml:

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/<group-id>/-/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project-id>/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>

    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project-id>/packages/maven</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group</groupId>
        <artifactId>package</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.18-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

.../.m2/settings.xml:

```
<settings>
   <servers>
     <server>
       <id>gitlab-maven</id>
       <configuration>
         <httpHeaders>
           <property>
             <name>deploy-token-username</name>
             <value>deploy-token-value</value>
           </property>
         </httpHeaders>
       </configuration>
     </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 1):

for jobs running in gitlab, configure `ci_settings.xml` and use property name `Job-Token`

```
       <server>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <configuration>
            <httpHeaders>
                <property>
                    <name>Job-Token</name>
                    <value>${env.CI_JOB_TOKEN}</value>
                </property>
            </httpHeaders>
        </configuration>
    </server>
```

when running maven locally, use `Private-Token` property name in `.m2/settings.xml`

```
 <server>
  <id>gitlab-maven</id>
  <configuration>
    <httpHeaders>
      <property>
        <name>Private-Token</name>
        <value>tOk3n</value>
      </property>
    </httpHeaders>
  </configuration>
</server>
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/